# Should I use "in the second half" or "on the second half" when talking about goals during game?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

"Scored 2 goals **in** the second half of his last game" or "Scored 2 goals **on** the second half of his last game" or "Scored 2 goals **during** the second half of his last game". Which one is more correct?

Comment: "In" must be used in this context.

Comment: Can you explain why exactly?

Comment: **In** is used to indicates a period of time during which an event happen. (Here the event is- **Scored two goals** )

Comment: **During** may indicates same meaning but it doesn't focus on event, but on period of time when the event happened.Here in this sentence if you used "during" then more focus will be upon "the period when it happened " not "the event itself "

Comment: You could Google both phrases and see the difference